# How to deploy local development server (kie-server) (jboss)

Tags: docker-compose, jboss, drools, redhat, jbpm

I am using JBoss (Red Hat) product jBPM and have taken the docker images of kie-server and drools-wb (i.e. drools workbench).

I have brought up my docker images successfully and am able to navigate to business central ([https://localhost:8080/business-central]).

I want to run decision services on my local development server.

But when I hit 'deploy' for my decision service I get a popup message

```
Deployment was skipped, couldn't find any server running in 'development' mode.
```

So then I navigated to the server configuration page. I added a server configuation, but I am missing a remote server to use. (e.g. second image below)

As an example, the below image shows a tutorial I was watching where a remote server is in use.[image]

[image: business central showing my server configurations]

I can insert my docker compose below.

```
services:  
  kie-server:
    image: jboss/kie-server-showcase:latest
    restart: unless-stopped
    container_name: kie-server
    ports:
      - 8180:8080
    links:
      - drools-wb:kie-wb

  drools-wb:
    image: jboss/business-central-workbench-showcase:latest
    restart: unless-stopped
    container_name: drools-wb
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kie-server must calls the workbench rest API for automatic registration, at the time, the kie-server will tell workbench what is the deployment api address, and then workbench can calls the deployment api to 'deploy' rule jar.

About how to configure, you can refre to [Kie-server dockerfile](https://github.com/jboss-dockerfiles/business-central/blob/master/kie-server/showcase/Dockerfile)

In this file, you can see more configure item.
There have three items is about your problem:
KIE_SERVER_CONTROLLER, KIE_SERVER_LOCATION and KIE_MAVEN_REPO

KIE_SERVER_CONTROLLER identifies the API call prefix of the workbench, kie-server will use this address for registration to workbench at the start time.

KIE_SERVER_LOCATION identifies the API call prefix of the kie-server, workbench will use this address for deployment rule jar.

KIE_MAVEN_REPO is kie-server use to download the rule jar of deployment.

KIE_SERVER_CONTROLLER: http://*workbench_external_ip_address*:*port* **/kie-wb/rest/controller**
KIE_SERVER_LOCATION: http://*kie_external_ip_address*:*port* **/kie-server/services/rest/server**
KIE_MAVEN_REPO: http://*workbench_external_ip_address*:*port* **/kie-wb/maven2**

You also can look the [document](https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/7.54.0.Final/drools-docs/html_single/index.html#_ch.kie.server)
, get the more detail.